# Are generator function's local variable stored on Stack or Heap?

Tags: javascript, optimization, heap-memory, generator, v8

In this article:
https://wingolog.org/archives/2013/06/11/ecmascript-generators-from-a-performance-perspective, it mentioned that:

> In a generator function, V8 stores local variables on the  heap
>   instead of on the stack.

but it also contradicts itself with this next passage:

> The exception to this case is when you yield and there are 
>   temporaries on the stack. Recall in my article on V8's  baseline
>   compiler that the full-codegen is a stack machine.  It allocates slots
>   to named locals, but temporary values go  on the stack at run-time,

The part that I don't understand is that generator functions always use yield, and I would assume that the **suspension** mentioned in the article refers to **yield** statement.

Comment: What article? You didn't link to it.

Comment: Also how is mentioning an exception to a case a contradiction?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks!

Comment: The second paragraph you quoted is not talking about generators, it's describing how the V8 baseline compiler works in general.

Comment: It's describing an exception to something that was described in the two paragraphs between the two quotes.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sure It's talking generators, it mentions when you yield. yield is only a thing in generators and enumerators.

Comment: When it says "It allocates slots to named locals", it's referring to what it said in "my article on V8's baseline compiler".

Comment: @Barmar gotcha I think that's what Jonas was explaining to me, the temporary values refers to literals as opposed to variables (named locals). The terminology in that blogpost can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the article is missing an example:

```
  return 12 + yield 5
```

In this case, 12 has to be allocated on the stack, and when suspending the iterator, it has to be copied off the stack, and then onto the stack again when the iterator continues. The second paragraph talks about "temporaries" (12 in this case), not about "variables".

Comment: so temporary **12** will be in the stack and if we declared var x = 5, x will be stored on the heap?

Comment: Yes, thats how I understand it.